# Present ViewController from UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

In my `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` method I want to jump the user to a specific view controller.  I can easily get the VC itself from the storyboard:

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "beach")
```

What I'm not entirely sure of though is now how to actually present it, since I don't have an object handy to call presentViewController on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your root is navigationVC

```
if let nav = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't think to go out to the app delegate to get the root window.

Comment: you mean it works or you implement it out of AppDelegate ?

Comment: It works.  I don't have a `self.window` as this is just an NSObject class, but by querying the AppDelegate to get the window I can then use the code you showed.

Comment: OK , keep going